# Class not found exception netbeans spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, netbeans

Error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebApplication1.SourcePackages.Domain.UserService

Here is part of the the dispatcher-servlet.xml code

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />


<bean id="UserService" class="WebApplication1.SourcePackages.Domain.UserService" />

<context:component-scan base-package="WebApplication1.SourcePackages.Controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

And here are screenshot of the files:

[image: screenshot]

UserController

```
package Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import Service.UserService;
import Domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/userRegistration.htm")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUserForm(ModelMap model)
{
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute(user);
    return "userForm";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    userService.add(user);
    return "UserSuccess";
}

}
```

User.java

```
package Domain;
```

/**
 *
 * @author fiona
 */
    public class User {

```
private String name;
private String password;
private String gender;
private String country;
private String aboutYou;
private String[] community;
private Boolean mailingList;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getAboutYou() {
    return aboutYou;
}
public void setAboutYou(String aboutYou) {
    this.aboutYou = aboutYou;
}
public String[] getCommunity() {
    return community;
}
public void setCommunity(String[] community) {
    this.community = community;
}
public Boolean getMailingList() {
    return mailingList;
}
public void setMailingList(Boolean mailingList) {
    this.mailingList = mailingList;
}

}
```

UserService.java
    package Service;

```
import Domain.User;

public class UserService {

public void add(User user) {
    //Persist the user object here. 
    System.out.println("User added successfully");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you have included the folder structure "WebApplication1.SourcePackages" in the class name for the bean and in the package name for component scan.
It is not a package name. "WebApplication1" is the name of the NetBeans project. "SourcePackages" is the name of the structure which contains all Java packages and classes for the project.

In your Spring config file, you just need to provide the fully qualified class name which is the package name for the class followed by the class name.

Sample provided below

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="userService" class="Service.UserService" />

<context:component-scan base-package="Controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

Comment: Thank you. But it still did not solve my prob and it still shows the class not found error like this Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Service.UserService.

Comment: @FionaHuang How are you deploying and executing the Web App? Are you running it within Net Beans or are you packaging it into a war and then deploying it into an external web container?

Comment: I ran it within the netbeans and I can post more code I had

Comment: I basically follow the source code of this one: https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-annotation-controller-1.html

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check. Specifically I have made the id for the UserService to camel case. Also, please provide code for UserService and UserController.

Comment: Updated and UserService should be under the folder of service package and user under the domain package(I accidentally put it wrong previously) Still showed the same mistake rn

Comment: If you have moved the UserService class to the Service package, please update the class name for it in the Bean Config XML file as "Service.UserService" and then execute. I have updated my answer with the same.